# VLOOKUP (or INDEX/MATCH) through multiple columns, but get value from other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Hope to have a relatively simple question.

I use VLOOKUP every day, for comparing 2 lists of itemnumbers and corresponding stock.

In a new situation itemnumbers are not longer in only one column, but the correct one could be in column A, B or C. While the stock is always in F.

Is it possible with VLOOKUP, or INDEX/MATCH to fill the corresponding stock in the orange cells, according to the itemnumber in one of three columns?

Many thanks in advance, Richard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

We want to lookup the word *hello* in the table from **A1** to **H14** and retrieve the associated value from column **J**

Pick some cell, say **K1**, and enter:

Hello

Then in another cell enter the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX(J1:J14,MIN(IF($A$1:$H$14=K1,ROW($A$1:$H$14)-ROW($A$1)+1)))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks! It's working, just reaaaaally slow, after applying down the formula 60.000 rows. It takes a while for the bottom rows to be updated (5mins).

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGRAGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$C$9)/($A$1:$C$9=B19),1))
```